# Kubernetes : How to connect production and non-production Azure CLI simultaneously through windows system?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-cli

I need to connect production and non-production environment using Azure CLI simultaneously through my windows system. I have access of both the environments and I have kube config file for both environment as well.

I am newbie to AKS so I am managing both file in my system and connecting either of environment using config file by renaming other file. e.g I have two file in my directory namely as `C:\Users\foo\.kube` with file name **config** and **config-nonprod**. So now I logged in to Azure CLI using below commands

- az login --scope foo
- az account set --subscription bar

Now if I run `kubectl get ns` command it will list the available namespace for production as my current config file is set to production.

Now if I want to connect non-prod environment then I just simply rename current **config** file to **config-prod** and current **config-nonprod** file to **config**. If I run `kubectl get ns` command then now it will list the available namespace for non-prod environment.

I don't want to do this exercise every time. I need any way by which I can connect both the environment simultaneously.

Prompt assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The standard Kubernetes tools support a `KUBECONFIG` environment variable which points at the config file, and in my setup I have a script that can change that variable to point at one cluster or the other.  The tools only support one cluster at a time, though; `kubectl get ns` can't get the namespaces from both clusters at the same time.